# How to get box input filed and small icon inside box using ionic 2?

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I want to display the input box but i am getting the line and also i wanted to display the small image icon inside the box.And i am getting only line.

Below is the screen what should i am trying to get:
[image: the screen what should i am trying to get]

Below is code what i had tried:

```
<ion-input type="number"
           place holder="Credit Card number"
           pattern="[0-9]{16}"></ion-input>
```

Comment: I'm really interested in your Input Design.. could you share the css code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-input type="number" place holder="Credit Card number"  pattern="[0-9]{16}"></ion-input>
    <ion-icon name="your_icon_name" item-right primary></ion-icon>
</ion-item>
```

EDIT: for styling you can set it in corresponding scss file

```
     ion-item {
             border-radius: 30px !important;
             border: 1px solid #ffffff;
/*other attributes*/
    }
```

The above style will be aplicable for all ion-items in your html file. In case you want it to be for only one input box, set a class for the ion item and set the corresponding style.

Comment: I am getting line by using your code,but i wanted to get rounded box as input field

Comment: @ Suraj Rao it is displaying cylindrical shape but i want rectangle shape

Comment: change or remove border radius

Comment: you mentioned rounded box

Comment: how can i get rectangular box?

Comment: remove border-radius from scss

Comment: ok its fine,How can i get (/) between month and year can u please tell me..